# Why isn't tilde expansion performed on the input to read?

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

Why has tilde expansion not occurred in the output of this script?

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

read -p "Enter filename: " fname
if [[ -d $fname ]]
then
        echo "$fname is a directory"
else
        echo "$fname is not a directory"
fi
```

Output:

```bsh
$ bash -x test_cd.sh 
+ read -p 'Enter filename: ' fname
Enter filename: ~/Music
+ [[ -d ~/Music ]]
+ echo ' ~/Music is not a directory'
 ~/Music is not a directory
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That’s simply because `read` doesn’t perform tilde expansion before saving the string, neither is it performed on a variable content later. You can use `$HOME` instead and enter

```
$HOME/Music
```

or let the script test for `~/` and replace it (taken from [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/399439/246819)):

```bsh
case "$fname" in "~/"*)
  fname="${HOME}/${x#"~/"}"
esac
```

You can also use [`bash` Parameter Expansion](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe#search_and_replace) to replace `~/` with `$HOME` at the beginning of the string:

```
if [[ -d ${fname/#~\//$HOME\/} ]]
```

This variable is expanded before the substitution is performed.