# -f $file_name doesn't work when using ~/file_name but works when using /home/james/file_name

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, windows-subsystem-for-linux

This has been driving me nuts. I have a pretty simple script

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

read -p "Enter changeList.txt file name: " file_name

if  [ -f $file_name ]; then
    echo "Reading File..."
    cat $file_name | grep "Change " | cut -d ' ' -f 2
    echo "Process complete"
else
    echo >&2 "File Note Found."
    exit 1
fi 

echo "Exiting..."
exit 0
```

I pass it a file ~/changeList.txt, that fails. I pass it /home/james/changeList.txt, and it works. I try

```bsh
file_name=~/changeList.txt
[ -f $file_name ] && echo "true" || echo "false"
```

from my terminal and it returns true. 
I am using Ubuntu on wsl 2, and I am signed in as james.

Comment: Related: [Why isn't tilde expansion performed on the input to read?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1093906/why-isnt-tilde-expansion-performed-on-the-input-to-read)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tilde expansion happens before variable expansion. In an assignment, the right hand side value undergoes tilde expansion, so the variable is assigned the full path. See `man bash` for details.

Comment: Do you know if there is a way to do tilde expansion from a string coming in or should I just not pass in a tilde?

Comment: `man bash` mentions `set expand-tilde On` with `read -e`, but I haven't been able to make it work.

Comment: @JamesAyres There are a bunch of options (of varying degrees of complexity and reliability) under the stackoverflow question ["How to manually expand a special variable (ex: ~ tilde) in bash"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3963716/how-to-manually-expand-a-special-variable-ex-tilde-in-bash).